# Cannot inser Linux kernel module because of unresolved symbols

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a Linux kernel (v4.14.0) module which uses various symbols from the kernel. I am unable to insert the module when I use certain kernel functions; dmesg logs say that the symbol was not found.

I have looked at the /proc/kallsyms file and the symbol is present. Here's the dmesg log:
[346091.805540] largepages_fault: **Unknown symbol transparent_hugepage_flags (err 0)**
[346091.805585] largepages_fault: **Unknown symbol is_vma_temporary_stack (err 0)**

/proc/kallsyms says these symbols are present:

0000000000000000 D transparent_hugepage_flags
0000000000000000 T is_vma_temporary_stack

I was facing similar issues with other symbols but used the 'kallsyms_lookup_name' workaround. I am unable to do so for the symbols mentioned above because I don't use the symbols directly in my module but use 'transparent_hugepage_enabled' function which in turn uses the above symbols.

I have gone through various posts related to this in the forum such as including header files, GPL licensing the module.

Comment: GPL-licensed module should have access to `kallsyms_lookup_name`. But variable `transparent_hugepage_flags` isn't exported for the modules, so you cannot use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found out that kallsyms is not the list of exported symbols, rather a list of symbols in the kernel. I went on to modify the kernel to export these symbols, so that I could use them in my module.